# Boolean.FALSE not equal to false

Tags: java, reflection

So I was playing with `java.lang.reflect` stuff and tried to make something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301635/change-private-static-final-field-using-java-reflection). And here is my problem (maybe a bug):

The code for my method to set the field to true:

```
private static void setFinalStatic(Field field, Object newValue) throws Exception
{
    field.setAccessible(true);
    Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
    modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
    modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
    field.set(null, newValue);
}
```

The code where I print it:

```
setFinalStatic(Boolean.class.getField("FALSE"), true);
System.out.format("%s\n", false);                  //prints true
System.out.println(false);                         //prints false
System.out.format("%s\n", Boolean.FALSE);          //prints true
System.out.println(Boolean.FALSE);                 //prints true
System.out.println(Boolean.FALSE == false);        //prints false
System.out.format("%s\n", Boolean.FALSE == false); //prints true
```

When you use `System.out.format("%s", false)` it return "true", as expected but when you use `System.out.println(false)` it prints "false". And when I tried this `System.out.println(Boolean.FALSE == false)` it printed "false".

You you please explain this?

Comment: Please consider the types involved, `format` takes an `Object...` parameter, so `false` is boxed to a `java.lang.Boolean` (ie `Boolean.FALSE`), while `println` takes a `boolean` parameter and is used as is. A `boolean` is a different type than a `Boolean`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no bug, `Boolean.FALSE` that you overridden is used for autoboxing because `boolean` autoboxing is implemented by compiler silently calling `Boolean.valueOf()` method with following body:

```
public static Boolean valueOf(boolean b) {
    return (b ? TRUE : FALSE);
}
```

In your example `boolean` parameters passed to methods using `Object` type e.g. `System.out.format(String, Object...)` will be subject to autoboxing. They will be affected by your reflective change and `false` will become `true`.

Otherwise methods using `boolean` primitive won't be affected e.g. `System.out.println(boolean)` and `false` will stay `false`.

The two most interesting lines in your example are:

- `System.out.println(Boolean.FALSE == false)`

  The compiler is unboxing `Boolean.FALSE` by calling
  `Boolean.FALSE.booleanValue()` which due to your reflection override
  returns `true`. Since `true == false` you get `false`. This can be
  confirming by placing a breakpoint in `Boolean.booleanValue()`.
- `System.out.format("%s\n", Boolean.FALSE == false)`

  Although you do get `false` from  comparison as per point above, it will be autoboxed into a `Boolean` to match the `System.out.format(String, Object...)` method signature. This will output `true` due to your reflection override.

Comment: `valueOf` is not relevant in this case. It does not explain why `System.out.println(Boolean.FALSE == false)` returns false.

Comment: @Michael explained this case, it's due to unboxing for this comparision.

Answer (score 0):

> when you use System.out.println(false) it prints "false".

This boolean value is never autoboxed, so the change you make via reflection is not relevant.

Here is the call stack:

```
PrintStream::println(boolean x)
PrintStream::print(boolean b)
String::valueOf(boolean b)
```

`String.valueOf(boolean)` is implemented like this:

```
public static String valueOf(boolean b) {
    return b ? "true" : "false";
}
```

So the fact that you've changed the constant used by the wrapper class makes no difference. We never use the wrapper class.

> And when I tried this System.out.println(Boolean.FALSE == false) it
>   printed "false".

`Boolean.FALSE` is automatically unboxed to a primitive `true`. `true == false` is false.